# How to set variable value by your index on RAM?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I receive a pointer numeric value like: `0xbfe0e6ac` it is possible set `int foo` for example to value of `0xbfe0e6ac` that is another int in memory?

My scenario:

I am tried to implement functions for get next index from array passing the pointer value (like the above example) as parameter.

For example:

```
char * a = "baa";
char* b = "foo";

    printf("%c", cgetnext(&a)); // b
    printf("%c", cgetnext(&a)); // a
    printf("%c", cgetnext(&b)); // f
    printf("%c", cgetnext(&b)); // a
```

The single way that I can see to do this is: in `cgetnex()` save pointer of array passed like parameter into array and each call, check if the array passed as paramater was used before and get information of it, like lasindexused and pointer value into RAM.

Here is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  { int pLocation; int lastIndex; } POINTERINFORMATION;

int     __myIndex;
POINTERINFORMATION   pointersLocations[256];
int     pointersLocationsLength;
char *  temparr = NULL;


__myIndex = pointersLocationsLength = 0;

int 
    plAdd (int p)
    {
        if (plLen >= sizeof(pointersLocation)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            pointersLocation[pointersLocationsLength].pLocation = p;
            pointersLocation[pointersLocationsLength].lastindex = 0;
            pointersLocationsLength ++;
            return pointersLocationsLength;
        }
    }

int 
    getPointer (int p, POINTERINFORMATION ** out)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < pointersLocationsLength; i++)
        {
            if(pointersLocation[pointersLocationsLength].pLocation == p)
            {
                *out = makevariablefromponiter(pi.pLocation);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

char 
    cgetnext(char * arr) 
    {
        char * myarr; 
        const size_t size = sizeof(char *) + 1;

        myarr = malloc(size);

        if (NULL == arr){
            POINTERINFORMATION * pi;
            if (getPointer(p, &pi))
            {
                __myIndex = pi.lastindex;
                            myarr = makevariablefromponiter(pi.pLocation);
            }
        } else {
            myarr = strdup (arr);
        }

        if (strlen(myarr) == __myIndex) {
            return '\0';
        } else  {
            __myIndex ++;
            temparr = malloc(size);
            temparr = strdup(myarr);
            return myarr[__myIndex - 1];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, do something like this:

```
int *fooPtr = 0xbfe0e6ac;

foo = *fooPtr;
```

In fact, you can make it even more concise:

```
foo = *(int *) 0xbfe0e6ac;
```

Comment: another question: is an `int` sufficiente for save the pointer index value or I should to use `long`?

Comment: @Jack `int` should be big enough

Comment: I'm trying to implement it, with char but it gives: `ILD.c: In function ‘main’:
ILD.c:32: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast` how to fix this? my code: `char * f = "abc";
  char buf[256];
  if(sprintf(buf,"%p", &f) < 0)
   printf("FAIL");
  int p = atoi(buf);
  char * a = *(char *)p;`

Comment: @Jack change the last line of that to this: `char *a = (char *)(int *)p;`